# Responsive Table - jQuery resize bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive, css-tables

I would like to ask you for your opinion and help.

For my little framework I would like inherently applied responsiveness on tables. That means no classes, ids, etc.

I am using :before with data-attribute for moving `<thead>`. Problem here is when I have smaller :before than content. So I made little jQuery javascript to make it same height as TD is.

```
function WindowResize(returnWidth) {
    var Width = 0;
    var Height = 0;
    // IE Handler

    if (!window.innerWidth) {
        if (!(document.documentElement.clientWidth == 0)) {
            // Strict Mode

            w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

            h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else {
            // Quirks Mode

            w = document.body.clientWidth;

            h = document.body.clientHeight;
        }
    } else {
        //w3c

        w = window.innerWidth;

        h = window.innerHeight;
    }

    return (returnWidth) ? w : h;   
}

function setSameTDHeight(Width) {
    Width = parseInt(Width);

    //var TDList = document.getElementByTagName('TD'); 

    if (Width < 768) {

        $("td").each(
            function() {
                var TDHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
                $(this).before().css({'height': TDHeight});
            }           
        );
    }   
}

$(window).resize(
    function() {
        setSameTDHeight(WindowResize(true));
    }
);

$(document).ready(
    function() {
        setSameTDHeight(WindowResize(true));
    }
);
```

Here is jQuery am using.

And here is the bug am solving:

[image: overflow content bug]

This is on 500px width of window. Content of previous TD is overflowing its TD border. I used clear attribute, float attribute etc. Nothing worked for me.

Here is codepen.io of whole situation: http://codepen.io/Ernedar/pen/dpYxwg

**Can somebody help me solve this overflow?**

Using absolute position, classes, IDs is not allowed for me to use, since I need this to make it universal.

EDIT: Image accuracy from tried solution from Dekel: [image]

Comment: you have a fixed height so add **"overflow-y: auto;"** to prevent it

Comment: and other option is remove the line **$(this).before().css({'height': TDHeight});**

Comment: @Ernedar, Did you check the answer? Was it correct or you still have problems here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Removed the `height` of the td (not needed).
2. Added a `position: absolute` and `top: 0` to the table (since the flex caused some problems here and positioned the table in the middle [vertical] of the screen).
3. Added margin/padding (some with negative values) to the `td` and `td:before` to fix the positioning problems.

```js
function WindowResize(returnWidth) {
  var Width = 0;
  var Height = 0;
  // IE Handler

  if (!window.innerWidth) {
    if (!(document.documentElement.clientWidth == 0)) {
      // Strict Mode

      w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

      h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else {
      // Quirks Mode

      w = document.body.clientWidth;

      h = document.body.clientHeight;
    }
  } else {
    //w3c

    w = window.innerWidth;

    h = window.innerHeight;
  }

  return (returnWidth) ? w : h; 
}

function setSameTDHeight(Width) {
  Width = parseInt(Width);

  //var TDList = document.getElementByTagName('TD'); 

  $("td").each(
    function() {
      // we don't really need this:
      
      //var TDHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
      //$(this).before().css({'height': TDHeight});
    }   
  );
}

$(window).resize(
  function() {
    setSameTDHeight(WindowResize(true));
  }
);

$(document).ready(
  function() {
    setSameTDHeight(WindowResize(true));
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
tbody td {
  font-size: 12px;
}

thead th {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
}

td, th {
  padding: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }

  table, thead, tbody, tr, td, th {
    display: block;
  }

  thead {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  thead th {
    font-size: 0;
    color: transparent;
  }

  table tr {
    display: block;
  }
  table tr:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  table tr:before {
    display: block;
  }

  table td {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 40%;
  }
  table td:before {
    content: attr(data-title);
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: -65%;
  }
  table td:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.</td>
        <td data-title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.</td>
        <td data-title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.</td>
        <td data-title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.</td>
        <td data-title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Jméno">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Fusce consectetuer risus a nunc. Integer lacinia. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada.</td>
        <td data-title="Příjmení">Maximov</td>
        <td data-title="Věková šarže">25</td>
        <td data-title="Zaměření">Pilot</td>
        <td data-title="Životní situace">Employed</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Jméno">Evelyn</td>
        <td data-title="Příjmení">Headrow</td>
        <td data-title="Věková šarže">19</td>
        <td data-title="Zaměření">Student</td>
        <td data-title="Životní situace">Not Employed</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Jméno">Bernard</td>
        <td data-title="Příjmení">Milhouf</td>
        <td data-title="Věková šarže">37</td>
        <td data-title="Zaměření">Teacher</td>
        <td data-title="Životní situace">Employed</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Jméno">Angelika</td>
        <td data-title="Příjmení">deVille</td>
        <td data-title="Věková šarže">68</td>
        <td data-title="Zaměření">Designer</td>
        <td data-title="Životní situace">Retired</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And a link to the fixed codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLmOym

Comment: Let me check it and try it and if it works, bounty is yours. Thanks a lot.

Comment: EDIT: Tried, this still unfortunately do not solve the problem. It is not overflown from left side, true, but still it overflows from bottom to another table cell. Thanks for contribution, but problem is not solved yet.

Comment: Which browser did you check? And i'm not so sure I understand what you mean by "overflows from bottom to another table cell". Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Using Chrome, FF, Opera, Edge and IE 10 + 11. Overflow from the image is just shifted from left, to the end of the end of bordered rectangle. Added another image for you.

Comment: This is what I get (chrome) from the codepen in my answer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XLfGC.png

Comment: Yea, this is ok. Proven. Bounty is yours.

Comment: I see that there is some glitch in ie/firefox - will try to solve this too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125357/discussion-between-dekel-and-ernedar).